# Why is my Javascript import in ES6 not working? Unexpected token *

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

im currently trying to implement [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/) in my Project. I've tried to implement it through npm installation, but somehow my Browser constantly throws this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

I'm guessing it has something to with ES6, but I can't figure out how to fix it.
My Javascript code looks like this:

```js
import * as FilePond from 'filepond';
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview';

FilePond.registerPlugin(
    FilePondPluginImagePreview()
);

const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement,{
    allowImagePreview: true,

});

FilePond.setOptions({
    server: 'test/'
});
```

I've tried to google an answer to this but it seems like I can't find a solution to this one. I've red something about compiling the ES6 code with [Bable](https://babeljs.io/), but  don't really know..

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: You can only use `import` in modules. From a browser, you have to include `type=module` in the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Your browser is not ES6 compatible. You can try using the lastest version of Chrome, or compile your ES6 to ES5 using Babel. You can find tutorials and guides easily.

Comment: @Pointy That one actually did something even though it just changed the text of the error message. It now says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'FilePond' of undefined`

Comment: @Treast, all the browser latest versions support modules, not just Chrome.

Comment: You cannot import from `node_modules` without a bundler like webpack.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use FilePond in the browser AND you want to use the ES module version you can go for dynamic imports or a script tag with type `module`. Browser support isn't fantastic.

Another option is to use the UMD version of the library and simply include the script tag as described in the docs.

The third option would be to use Rollup or Webpack with Babel.

#### Dynamic Imports

```
<link href="./filepond.css" rel="stylesheet">
<input type="file"/>

<script>
import('./filepond.esm.js').then(FilePond => {
  FilePond.create(document.querySelector('input'));
});
</script>
```

#### Type Module

```
<link href="./filepond.css" rel="stylesheet">
<input type="file"/>

<script type="module" src="./filepond.esm.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener('FilePond:loaded', e => {
    const FilePond = e.detail;
    FilePond.create(document.querySelector('input'));
})
</script>
```

### Some other notes

```
FilePond.registerPlugin(
    FilePondPluginImagePreview()
);
```

Remove the `()`, those are not needed.

```
const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement,{
    allowImagePreview: true,
});
```

Plugins are automatically enabled so setting `allowImagePreview` to `true` is also not required.